# How to import XML to SQL Server when base nodes repeat

Tags: sql-server, xml, import, xsd, schema

I am importing generated XML files into a SQL Server database.  It's been working fine, but now I need additional information from a node that repeats, and I can't figure it out.  I am using VBScript with `SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkload.4.0` to import the files.  There are many `<file>` nodes in each file, and here a simplified as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samp_catalog version='1.0'>
  <file>
    <name>123.wav</name>
    <xyz>
      <a_samp>
        <a_one>1</a_one>
        <a_two>2</a_two>
        <a_three>3</a_three>
      </a_samp>
      <b_samp version='2.0'>
        <b_four>sample</b_four>
        <b_five>sample</b_five>
        <b_six>sample</b_six>
      </b_samp>
      <c_samp version='1.0'>
        <c_entry>
          <total_size>0</total_size>
          <sig>sample</sig>
          <type>SAMPLE</type>
          <data_size>256</data_size>
          <data encoding='string'></data>
        </c_entry>
      </c_samp>
      <c_samp version='1.0'>
        <c_entry>
          <total_size>0</total_size>
          <sig>sample</sig>
          <type>PHONE</type>
          <data_size>256</data_size>
          <data encoding='string'>15555551212</data>
        </c_entry>
      </c_samp>
      <c_samp version='1.0'>
        <c_entry>
          <total_size>0</total_size>
          <sig>sample</sig>
          <type>OTHER_SAMPLE</type>
          <data_size>256</data_size>
          <data encoding='string'></data>
        </c_entry>
      </c_samp>
    </xyz>
  </file>
</samp_catalog>
```

Without the repeating `c_samp` node, the schema was easy:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
  <xsd:element name = "samp_catalog" sql:is-constant = "1">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name = "file" sql:relation = "files" maxOccurs = "unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name = "name" type = "xsd:string" sql:field = "name" />
              <xsd:element name = "xyz" sql:is-constant = "1">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name = "a_samp" sql:is-constant = "1">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name = "a_one" type = "xsd:integer" sql:field = "a_one" />
                          <xsd:element name = "a_two" type = "xsd:integer" sql:field = "a_two" />
                          <xsd:element name = "a_three" type = "xsd:integer" sql:field = "a_three" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name = "b_samp" sql:is-constant = "1">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name = "b_four" type = "xsd:string" sql:field = "b_four" />
                          <xsd:element name = "b_five" type = "xsd:string" sql:field = "b_five" />
                          <xsd:element name = "b_six" type = "xsd:string" sql:field = "b_six" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

The important one is the second `data` element (of `type` PHONE), but importing them all is acceptable as well.  I have tried defining all 3 `c_samp`s in the schema and defining a `sql:field` for only the specified `data` element and defining it for all elements, however the import always results in `NULL` for everything under a `c_samp` element.

How can I get the repeating nodes to import into the database?

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter (might be your own answer). This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I haven't found an answer for what I was looking to do, but here is a work around I'm using for now.  In VBScript, after loading the file with `Microsoft.XMLDOM` I loop through the file and find all `type` nodes whose text value is `PHONE` and then create a new element and append it to `b_samp` with its sibling `data`'s text value.

VBScript:

```
Set nodes = xmlFile.selectNodes("//type")
For Each node in nodes
  If node.text = "PHONE" Then
    Set phoneNode = xmlFile.CreateElement("phone")

    For Each child in node.ParentNode.ChildNodes
      If child.nodeName = "data" Then phoneNode.text = child.text
    Next

    For Each child in node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes
      If child.nodeName = "b_samp" Then child.appendChild phoneNode
    Next
  End If
Next
```

Then save the file with a new name to leave the original intact, and import it with a new schema adding this line right after the `b_six` element:

```
<xsd:element name = "phone" type = "xsd:string" sql:field = "phone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a *stored procedure* in SQL-Server and pass over the XML *as-is*. Use SQL Server's abilities to read the XML without a schema.

The following code will extract all information from the XML given.

Just do something like

```
CREATE dbo.ImportMyXML(@xml XML)
AS
BEGIN
    --Code here
END
GO
```

Within the `BEGIN END` you write this query (out-commented the `INSERT INTO` to test the query's result:

```
--INSERT INTO YourTargetTable(col1,col2,col3,...)
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/samp_catalog/file/name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS name
      ,a_samp.value(N'(*/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS a_one
      ,a_samp.value(N'(*/text())[2]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS a_two
      ,a_samp.value(N'(*/text())[3]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS a_three

      ,b_samp.value(N'@version',N'nvarchar(max)') AS b_version
      ,b_samp.value(N'(*/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS b_one
      ,b_samp.value(N'(*/text())[2]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS b_two
      ,b_samp.value(N'(*/text())[3]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS b_three

      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(../@version)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS c_version
      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(total_size/text())[1]','int') AS c_total_size
      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(sig/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c_sig
      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(type/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c_type
      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(data_size/text())[1]','int') AS c_data_size
      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(data/@encoding)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c_data_encoding
      ,NodesWith_c_entry.value(N'(data/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c_data_text

FROM @xml.nodes(N'samp_catalog/file/xyz') AS A(xyz)
OUTER APPLY xyz.nodes('a_samp') AS B(a_samp)
OUTER APPLY xyz.nodes('b_samp') AS C(b_samp)
OUTER APPLY xyZ.nodes('*/c_entry') AS D(NodesWith_c_entry);
```

With the XML given the result is this:

```
+---------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| name    | a_one | a_two | a_three | b_version | b_one  | b_two  | b_three | c_version | c_total_size | c_sig  | c_type       | c_data_size | c_data_encoding | c_data_text |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 123.wav | 1     | 2     | 3       | 2.0       | sample | sample | sample  | 1.0       | 0            | sample | SAMPLE       | 256         | string          | NULL        |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 123.wav | 1     | 2     | 3       | 2.0       | sample | sample | sample  | 1.0       | 0            | sample | PHONE        | 256         | string          | 15555551212 |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 123.wav | 1     | 2     | 3       | 2.0       | sample | sample | sample  | 1.0       | 0            | sample | OTHER_SAMPLE | 256         | string          | NULL        |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
```